# How do I use "Into" LINQ expression in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, linq, .net-4.0

I'm converting from C# this LINQ expression. However, it does not seem to work.

C#

```
 return (from w in fishSticks
         group w by w.FishQty into g
         orderby g.Key descending
         select g).First().First();
```

VB

```
Return (From w In fishSticks
        Group w By w.FishQty Into g()
        Order By g.Key Descending
        Select g).First().First()
```

Visual Studio turns `Into g` into `Into g()` itself and then gives me this error:

> Definition of method 'g' is not
>   accessible in this context.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[VB.Net has different group syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531412.aspx)

The correct syntax is

```
Dim q = (From w In fishSticks
         Group By Quantity = w.FishQty Into g = Group
         Order By Quantity Descending
         Select g).First().First()
```

Comment: Excellent, it works perfectly. VB is the bane of my life. Thanks for your help.