# LINQ version of Where In Subquery With Max and Group By

Tags: sql, vb.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, where-in

How would you use LINQ to Entities to accomplish the following query.

```
SELECT [id] ,[value1], [value2], [dateValue]
FROM table
WHERE dateValue IN (
    SELECT MAX(dateValue)
    FROM table
    GROUP BY id
)
```

There are multiple entries in the table with the same id, so I just want one of each id with the greatest date value. Also, the dateValue includes a time component down to the milliseconds and wont be duplicated.

I know LINQ To Entities doesn't support the `IN` keyword however I've read you can still work with subqueries by using the `context.tableName.Any()` method or by adding a query inside the Select part.

```
Using context = ContextProvider.GetContext()
    Dim table = context.tableName

    Dim query = _
        From rows In table _
        Select New ClassName With _
               { _
                   .Id = rows.Id, _
                   .Value1 = rows.Value1, _
                   .Value2 = rows.Value2, _
                   .DateValue = rows.DateValue _
               }

    Return query.ToList()
End Using
```

Given the above, I'm not sure if there should be a `Where table.Any(...` in the query, or a `.DateValue = subquery` in the Select, to get what I want. And in either situation I'm not sure how to format the expression.

Comment: Why do you group by id in the subsquery if you just want the MAX(dateValue)? Do you want the top 1 record per ID  with the MAX(dateValue)? Then the sql query is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, there are multiple entries with the same id and I just want 1 entry per id with the greatest date for that id.

Comment: What is the primary key of your table?

Comment: The primary key is id and mainDate, the second of which is unused.

Comment: I've removed the `DISTINCT` keyword as after some more testing, I believe it isn't doing anything for the query.

Comment: If `mainDate` is not used, `Id` *must* be unique, otherwise EF won't even be able to get the right data for you. But apart form that, Tim Schmelter's approach is the way to go here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your sql is already incorrect because there is no relation between the subquery and the main-query other than the date. If you have an ID with a dateValue that is the max-dateValue of another ID you get this record with the wrong ID.

So if you want the record with the greatest Date per ID i would do:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [id] ORDER BY [dateValue] DESC),
          [id] ,[value1], [value2], [dateValue]
    FROM table
)
SELECT [id] ,[value1], [value2], [dateValue]
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

In LINQ this should work (i'm not that familiar with Linq-To-Entities):

```
Dim query = From row In table
            Group row By row.Id into idGrp
            Let MaxDatePerID = idGrp.Max(Function(r) r.DateValue)
            From idRow In idGrp
            Where idRow.DateValue = MaxDatePerID 
            Select New ClassName With 
            { 
               .Id = idRow.Id, 
               .Value1 = idRow.Value1, 
               .Value2 = idRow.Value2, 
               .DateValue = idRow.DateValue 
            }
```

Comment: I've ran the regular SQL query against the table and it does give me back the correct results. I've even double checked the dates individually by using `SELECT MAX(dateValue) FROM table Where id = ...` for each id in the table and the dates match up. I'm not saying your method is incorrect, I'll give it a try, but my SQL statement doesn't seem to be incorrect like you suggest.

Comment: @JeremyK: consider these 3 rows: 1) `ID=1,DateValue=2014/9/7` 2) `ID=1,DateValue=2014/9/8` 3)  `ID=2,DateValue=2014/9/7`. Now you get also the first record even if it's not the max-date for this ID because that date is a date which is the max-date of another ID.

Comment: Oh, I see. That could be a valid concern for some. I'll never get that situation due to the date being a dateTime value down to the milliseconds. I should have been more clear about that. Sorry.

Comment: @JeremyK: a bug is still a bug even if it's unlikely that you'll notice it. Often these are the nastiest issues because you never recognize them.

Comment: That is true. I've verified that the SQL does work correctly. Although I also had to include into the first part `WHERE NOT dateValue IS NULL`. Haven't verified the LINQ yet, but it looks like you've got the right answer. Thanks.

Comment: In case anyone uses the LINQ in this answer, the [format for Group By Into](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668163/how-do-i-use-into-linq-expression-in-vb-net) is slightly different in VB.NET.